# Get the largest absolute difference in an array Python

Tags: python, arrays

I want to do a for loop that can basically do the absolute difference between every 2 elements of the array until it reaches all of them and then print the highest absolute difference.

```
arr = []

n = int(input("number of elements in array: "))

for i in range(0, n):
        arr.append(input('insert element: '))
```

I've done this already but I would like to know how slow this method is compared to making the absolute difference between the
first and last element after sorting the array.

EXAMPLE

```
Input: {2, 7, 3, 4, 1, 9}

Output: 8 (|1 – 9|)
```

This is what I have tried:

```
arr = [] 
n = int(input("número de elementos do array : ")) 

for i in range(0, n): 
    arr.append(int(input('escreva os elementos: '))) 
    arr.sort() 
    print(arr[-1] - arr[0])
```

Comment: do you want to include your code here so we can see how efficient it is? you've only included the code to get the inputs!

Comment: ````
arr = []

n = int(input("número de elementos do array : "))

for i in range(0, n):
        arr.append(int(input('escreva os elementos: ')))

arr.sort()

print(arr[-1] - arr[0])
````

Answer (score 0):

As I understood about your query.
Sorting the element and then comparing first & last one is much faster than finding highest difference via iterating through list. This is because when sorting happens internally, as it moves forward it needs to compare with less values because if value is higher than last sorted value it directly appends next to it but if value is less then it just moves one value back rather than starting over again.
But comparing through all possible pairs in list takes much more time as it has to start from first value over again since we don't know which comparing will be highest.
So sorting is much faster to find largest difference than iterating for every possible pair with for loop in list.

I hope I got your query right :)

***UPDATED***

so the main question is about finding a way to find largest diff in a list with for loop and which should be faster so here it is.

In my opinion below code will be even faster than sorting and finding largest diff. Because here in this code we only need to iterate in list once and we will have answer of largest diff. No need to iterate every possible pair of value.

I think this may help :)

```py
list_a = []

n = int(input("number of elements in array: "))        

for i in range(0, n):
    # store input after converting to integer.
    list_a.append(int(input('insert element: ')))
            
'''to store largest difference of two current numbers in every eteration'''
largest_diff_so_far = 0;

'''list to store that two numbers we are comparing'''
actual_diff_number = None;

'''start from first number in list. we don't need to go through every possible pair so just picking first number without for loop.'''
first = list_a[0]
        
'''here we iterate through all number only once till last number in
list'''
for second in list_a :
    '''first find diff of current two value'''
    current_diff = second - first

    '''as we can see when current_diff is larger then previous largest diff we will update their value'''
    if largest_diff_so_far == 0 or current_diff > largest_diff_so_far:

        '''if first value in list is largest than all then the current diff will be negative and in that case we will run below if code and continue the code so that it will not over -ride anything in remaining code'''
        if current_diff < 0:
            ''' since the diff is negative we will store its absolute value in largest diff variable.'''
            largest_diff_so_far = abs(current_diff)

            ''' since first value is largest then all means it is larger than current second also, so in actual_diff_number we will store values in reverse order, so that our largest value which is stored in first variable will be second in list and by this in later iteration we will avoid over-writing of this largest value'''
            actual_diff_number = [second, first]

            ''' we will also update first variable's value to second variable's value since it smaller than previous value of first and by this next iteration will use this value for diff rather than initial value of first variable which was largest.'''
            first = second
            continue

        '''if above condition is not the case than rest of the below code will run'''
        '''largest diff will be current_diff'''
        largest_diff_so_far = current_diff

        '''storing actual number whose diff is largest till now.'''
        actual_diff_number = [first, second]
            
        '''below is main part for saving time. if in current process we find diff which is in minus means our second value is even less than first, in that case we no longer need to carry forward that first value so we will update first value to our current second value and will also update largest diff that is stored previously. since our first value is less than previous first value then our diff will also increase from previous diff.'''
    elif current_diff < 0:
        first = second
        '''update largest diff with new first value'''
        largest_diff_so_far = actual_diff_number[1] - first

        '''update actual diff number's first value in that list'''
        actual_diff_number[0] = first
        
'''finally print answer since after finishing for loop largest_diff_so_far and actual_diff_number contains the answer that we are finding.'''
print(actual_diff_number, largest_diff_so_far)
```

Comment: HI Naveen, thanks for your answer but I was looking for an explanation on how to do it using only for loops. I know that it takes way longer than sorting

Comment: ok if your query is finding about finding the actual process for finding largest to diff then above I have edited my answer by including the actual code which will do what you need.

Comment: Hi! First of all just want to thank you for taking your time to solve this and help me. I was testing it and I came up with an error. If you repeat the same elements at the end of the array it will do the asolut difference between those 2 and not the bigger and smaller.
Ill give you an example : the inout give 5 elements, 12414,6456,6356,1,1 and the output would be 0.
I cant seem to figure it out but thanks anyways!

Comment: Found another one but cant seem to understand why itis acting this way
number of elements in array: 5
insert element: 123
insert element: 23
insert element: 56
insert element: 75
insert element: 45
[23, 75] 52

Comment: Hi! Thank you for pointing out error in code. I have figured it out and quick fixed it above in my answer. The reason for all above behavior is first value becoming the largest than other. Since in that case both if blocks will run and first largest value will be erased by second if block. So I have updated it. so Thank you for pointing it out. If again any error arises feel free to point it out. Good Luck :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are fine with numpy, there's a way to do so.

Firstly, you need to find all the possible non-duplicate solutions from the given input using `itertools.combinations`

```
from itertools import combinations

alist = [2, 7, 3, 4, 1, 9]

all_comb = list(combinations(alist, 2))
[(2, 7), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 1), (2, 9), (7, 3), (7, 4), (7, 1), (7, 9), (3, 4), (3, 1), (3, 9), (4, 1), (4, 9), (1, 9)]
```

With this, you can use `np.diff` to find the differences for every tuple.

```
abs_diff = abs(np.diff(all_comb)).flatten()
array([5, 1, 2, 1, 7, 4, 3, 6, 2, 1, 2, 6, 3, 5, 8])
```

Finally, you can get the index of the maximum difference using `np.argmax`.

```
all_comb[abs_diff.argmax()]
Out[147]: (1, 9)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = [] 
n = int(input("número de elementos do array : "))

my_min, my_max = None, None
for i in range(0, n): 
    arr.append(int(input('escreva os elementos: ')))
    if my_min is None or abs(arr[i]) < my_min:
        my_min = arr[i]
    if my_max is None or abs(arr[i]) > my_max:
        my_max = arr[i]
    print(f"{abs(my_max - my_min)} (|{my_max} - {my_min}|)")
```

You can achieve this just by "emembering" the number with highest and lowest abs value

Comment: Didn't understand what you did. The  arr.append(int(input('escreva os elementos: '))) is meant to be the elements added to the array and it doesnt loop the n times it should

Comment: You do not need the array, you can just keep min and max of the array